# Passing Normals Within a Struct

Tags: ios, struct, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to draw a 3D cube in OpenGL ES 2.0 iOS. I made a struct through which I'm trying to house the various information related to the cube (postion coordinates, texture mapping, normals). Now I need to tell OpenGL where to find the normals within this struct. Everything compiles and renders correctly, but the very last line that I show below gives me this warning:

`Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'unsigned long' to parameter of type 'const GLvoid *' (aka 'const void *')`

Why is my code returning an unsigned long? I don't know how to modify this to get the pointer that the line is asking for. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct {
    GLKVector3 positionCoordinates;
    GLKVector2 textureCoordinates;
    GLKVector3 normalCoordinates;
} VertexData;
```

The coordinate data:

```
VertexData cameraVertices[] = {
    //{ position x,   position y, position z}, {texture}, {normalX, normalY, normalZ}
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },   // rightward facing (+X)
    { { 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },
    { { 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },
    { { 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}, { 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },

    { { 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f} },   // upward facing (+Y)
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f} },
    { { 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f} },
    { { 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f} },
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f} },
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f} },

    { {-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, {-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },   // leftward facing (-X)
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, {-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, {-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, {-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, {-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}, {-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f} },

    { {-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f} },   // downward facing (-Y)
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f} },
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f} },
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f} },
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f} },
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f} },

    { { 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f} },   // forward facing (+Z)
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f} },
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f} },
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f} },
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f} },
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f} },

    { { 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f} },   // rear facing (-Z)
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f} },
    { { 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f} },
    { { 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f} },
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f} },
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f} },
};
```

And the relevant lines of code (essentially within viewDidLoad):

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), offsetof(VertexData, positionCoordinates));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), offsetof(VertexData, normalCoordinates));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the fundamental issue here is that the `offsetof` macro does not return a pointer! It returns the offset as a `size_t`. Since the size of `size_t` and the size of `GLvoid *` may differ, do not use the result of `offsetof (...)` this way.

What you ought to do is: `(GLubyte *)0 + offsetof (...)`.

Comment: Thanks. One more question before I click the accept button: Any idea why the first call to `glVertexAttribPointer` doesn't throw a warning but the second one does? I'm using the same fundamental approach, so I'm confused about why the different behavior. Thank you again!

Comment: @usr55410: Not really, it must be something different about the macro when the offset is 0. Did the changes I suggested correct your problems?

Comment: Yes, they did. Was just looking for that final clarification for future reference. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a simpler way. All I needed to do is cast this to a void *.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void *)offsetof(VertexData, normalCoordinates));
```

Comment: I would avoid doing this for portability sake, `size_t` is only required to be large enough to address `SIZE_MAX`-many elements in an array. It is defined independently from the size of a pointer. What happens if you are on a system with a 64-bit pointer type and only 32-bit `size_t`? Half of the pointer you just created through casting comes from an invalid memory location. But if you use `size_t` in pointer arithmetic you can completely avoid this issue - `size_t` will never have a size **greater** than a pointer, but could be smaller. This issue might pop up on the iPhone 5S, for instance.